Selenium "Unable to locate element" with LINK_TEXT or XPATH
I'm using this code...
class Browser:
    browser, service = None, None

    def __init__(self, driver:str):
        self.service = Service(driver)
        self.browser = webdriver.Edge() #webdriver.Edge(service=self.service)

    def open_page(self, url: str):
        self.browser.get(url)

    def close_browser(self):
        self.browser.close()

    def add_input(self, by: By, value: str, text: str):
        field = self.browser.find_element(by=by, value=value)
        field.send_keys(text)
        time.sleep(1)

    def click_button(self, by: By, value: str):
        button = self.browser.find_element(by=by, value=value)
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1)

    def login_kelio(self, user: str, password: str):
        self.add_input(by=By.ID, value="username", text=user)
        self.add_input(by=By.ID, value="password", text=password)
        self.click_button(by=By.XPATH, value='//input[@value="Confirm"]')
        self.click_button(by=By.XPATH, value='//div[@type="PortailVignetteLienExec"][1]')
        element = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(), "Consultar balance")]')))
        self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

To click this button with -Consultar balance-
<a class="boutonAction defaultActionBouton" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:fcDoAction('AFFICHER__CD')">Consultar balance</a>

But i always get errors either with XPATH or LINK_TEXT
I.E:

"NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"

Here is the absolute path to the element:

/html/body/div#bwtcontainer/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/iframe/html/body/form#formAction/table#tableContenu/tbody/tr/td/div.contenu/table/tbody/tr/td/div#badgeuseVirtuelleGTP/table/tbody/tr/td/fieldset/table/tbody/tr/td/a.boutonAction.defaultActionBouton


(By.LINK_TEXT, '//*[contains(text(), "Consultar balance")]') - this is incorrect. It should be By.XPATH. Also, check for the presence of IFRAME.

@Shawn yes, it was a typo due to some of my tests, i was using xpath, can you explain why i should look for IFRAME?

If the target element is wrapped within an IFRAME, then you need to switch the driver context to that iframe first, then perform the required action. Read about iframes from this link

@Shawn you are the boss! switching to the iframe solved the issue.

Switching to the iframe before clicking the button solved the issue, here is how i did it.
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 5)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')))
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Consultar balance')))
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Thanks to @Shawn.

You should use EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it() for the IFRAME. I've updated the code in your answer. See if it makes sense. It takes advantage of the wait for the IFRAME and for the link. Let me know if you have any questions.

@JeffC works like a charm with your updated.
